# How to get the first element without knowing what tag it is?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

How can I get the first element **without** knowing what tag it is?

For instance, I only know its parent `'.parent'`, but I want to get its child node of `<div>`

```
<div class="parent">
<div>
    <p>Loading...</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Sometimes, its child node is only a `<p>`

```
<div class="parent">
    <p>Loading...</p>
</div>
```

My attempt,

```
console.log($(".parent").firstChild); // but I get underfined
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this one:

```
$(".parent :first")
```

Comment: i will get `.parent` isn't with that?

Comment: I think you need a space between `.parent` and `:first`.

Comment: @tealou with this selector you will get the first element in your DOM that has as a class the `parent`.

Comment: i get `undefined` mate.

Comment: i get the same result - undefined.

Comment: @tealou if you change it to `first-child`. However I don't expect any difference. It seems strange to me.

Comment: my mistake earlier on. sorry. `.parent :first` - correct.

Comment: @tealou ok. no problem dude.

Comment: This one only gets the first instance of `.parent`. If that's the functionality you want, then cool. Otherwise, you can't get the first children of all `.parent`s with this code.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this.

```
$('.parent').children().first();
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.parent > :first-child').each(function() {
  console.log(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <p>test
    <a>subtest</a>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <del>test
    <a>subtest</a>
  </del>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <span>test
    <a>subtest</a>
  </span>
</div>
```